# OS X -- Set `Internal` flag on disk drive

Tags: macos, unix

I have an internal drive that OS X picks up as external? How do I tell the system that its actually internal?

```
$diskutil info disk0

   Device Identifier:        disk0
   Device Node:              /dev/disk0
   Part of Whole:            disk0

   ...stuff...

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No     <---- How do I get this to 'Yes'?
   Solid State:              Yes
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want this?  After reading the [man pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8) for `diskutil`, I am pretty sure that isn't suggesting a physical location but actually the `journal location`.  In which case, there is no real benefit for you to have it say one vs. another.

Comment: It's a minor gripe. The icons for the drives that are not 'Internal' show up orange as if they were thumb drives. If there's an easy fix for this that would be awesome.

Comment: Haha, I feel you there.  You should be able to change the icon though.  On a drive you like the icon of, click `Cmd+I` (or right click, `Get Info`).  Then in that window, click the icon (top left corner, I believe) and hit `Cmd + C`.  Do the same on the one to replace, but use `Cmd + V` instead.  That used to work when I had a mac a few years ago. If that still works, let me know and I can migrate it to an answer.